# Nothing but NAN values using raster interpolation in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, interpolation

I am trying to perform a raster interpolation of a contour shapefile with the intent of eventually creating a DEM. No matter what I try, I get NAN values, and nothing is working to fix it. I can't even begin to understand why this is happening, I would love to provide more detail if I had even the slightest idea what the problem was... I've tried changing the cell size, trying points, structure lines and break lines as the type of file, I've tried doing it as a TIN and IDW, changing the coordinate system to UTM (as suggested in another post)... Every possible solution that I can think of.

I've also tried going the grid interpolation route instead of the typical raster interpolation route, no dice. I get a different error with that route though...

[image]

I'm clutching at straws, but my guess is that something is wrong with my shapefile, though I can't figure it out. Any suggestions would be appropriated, though I am pretty incompetent with Python if that is the solution...

Comment: Have you tried adding the whole file path of a0000000b into the gdal_grid command in the text box? You can click the yellow pencil to edit this command.

Comment: Just tried it and it gave the same error. Thanks for trying.

Comment: Could you upload an example contour file you are using?

Comment: Rename the input file. There is a space in the file name that is messing stuff up!

Comment: That was just the way it was displayed, the way it was saved wasn't with a space. I tried getting rid of the space in the layer name too just to see if that would work and it didn't :(.

Comment: Also, what is the best way to upload a contour file? Sorry I'm fairly new the site. Also It was originally from an esri geodatabase, and was clipped in esri (from what i understand) which is how I got the area for the district I am trying to do. I don't know if that helps.

Comment: Have you tried exporting the layer from the gdb you are using? You keep mentioning a shapefile, but your input is not actually a shapefile. Looking at the gdal_grid command it is looking for a layer named a0000000b within the a0000000b.gdbtable file.
If I'm interpreting the input line correctly the actual layer name within the gdbtable is Contours_Clip which is of type MultiLineString. Exporting that layer to a shapefile and running the processes again should work - certainly does on 2.14.8 (LTR) when tested.

Comment: In addition I've tested running the grid interpolation tool with a gdbtable as input and indeed the tool fails with the same error as yours albeit the name of the layer is different.

Comment: Should the file be named "a0000000b" or perhaps is it "a000000b"?

Comment: Hey! Sorry for the delayed response. I actually found out that there was a DEM available for the area that I was looking for, so I ended up skipping this step after banging my head against my desk for hours. Running it again just to try for future reference, it seems like your solution works Phil G. I appreciate your input.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same "Nothing But NAN values using raster interpolation in QGIS" problem today. I discovered that I had created my altitude points layer in a different SRC than the rest of my project. So I right clicked on it, save as, and selected the SRC of my project (EPSG:3857). Then in Raster > Interpolation > Interpolation I picked this source layer and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your data into a projected CRS like UTMs. If your point data are in (for example) radian degrees lat/long, but your elevations are in meters above sea level, you will get the NaN error. The easy solution is to right click your csv or shapefile, then Save As..., give the file a new name and select a projected CRS like UTM. Create your interpolation from the reprojected file.